# MS SQL query results vary depending on set of columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Please help me find solution to the following issue.
I have 2 queries:

```
SELECT tu
FROM testview1
WHERE tu = 1;
SELECT *
FROM testview1
WHERE tu = 1;
```

First query returns 21 rows, second - 36.
testview1 is a view which has 3 colums, all of them are int.

```
CREATE VIEW testview1 AS
  SELECT
    rn,
    tu,
    id
  FROM t1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    rn,
    tu,
    id
  FROM t2
```

What could be a reason for such difference?

Comment: both query should returns same no of rows regardless of the columns selected

Comment: @MaeCandis, the first query. I don't understand why it returns less rows.

Comment: Can we see tables stricture and sample data, we can't test on nothing.

Comment: are you sure both query are exactly as you posted here ?

Comment: @Squirrel I don't think so

Comment: Data is here - https://mega.nz/#!LwQFABwZ!2bXatFB_XwVGthnjWrEhU5hCuisdP1gIk4qkXL2chP4

Comment: @Dmitriy With your data both queries return 36 rows

Comment: Here is a video of this issue - https://mega.nz/#!TtAiCbgA!m2WLJ6Y-hdbsMW5qNBAfRQL_Ob1eQPAunVUb25dYlpU

Comment: I cannot open video at work. Post here the actual execution plan for both queries

Comment: I tested this in my machine its work correctly,both the query returns same resultset

Comment: POST ACTUAL EXECUTION PLAN FOR BOTH QUERIES, the answer is there

Comment: this one is for query with wrong result -
 https://mega.nz/#!S0wSTJQT!1cGwPvi1OMpswICwoka2c3ZcKISm93ulzY4GJdpfAqo ths is a good one - https://mega.nz/#!7xJDVDpD!TLXbfnyO7x8FtozkEIbWC8-PYPlh77w-HPQr46plkpY

Comment: @Dmitriy please provid t1 and t2 data

Comment: t1 data - https://mega.nz/#!LshRjQ4I!Y7n_zuXtgP3CfpKd5MUE93jrmsq1cN4RLixScegEfmI t2 data - https://mega.nz/#!ewxUQZQZ!DiQYH9rLjyJiqNSaFE6pM3VyatLVQal36bCMG8qMQ2M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view has `top ()` without `order by`, so the result of this select depends on the order that server chooses to return you the rows.

Two queries produces 2 different plans because of different columns requested and server chooses `ODRERED` index scan in the "right" plan and `NOT ORDERED` in "wrong" plan.

As the result, different rows are filtered further and the final number of rows is different

Comment: this function gets 75 - records count in table t1 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[f_6sigm_extra_tickets]()
  RETURNS INT
  BEGIN
    DECLARE lim INT;
    SELECT lim = 75 - iif(count(id) > 75, 75, count(id))
    FROM t1
    RETURN lim
  END
GO
after that I union data from t1 with rows from t2 (top rows limited by result of this function). t2 always has mode than 75 rows.

Comment: Ok, my answer is wrong, it could be this function to limit output rows but it's not. Can you post ACTUAL plans instead of estimated, please? When you see ACTUAL number of rows you can find WHERE they are lost. Your plans are estimated only

Comment: good - https://mega.nz/#!OoRTiSxS!CetHkhhTz5N1LfE4ongl-wMUb2PAQ1iFTkmOsfUgVNs bad - https://mega.nz/#!24xmGRzA!AI9rmh6MewFqO5xmIXDH3hEIVBYBtDxPAsTq29bV7pU now I see that I get 19 rows from t2 instead of 34, but can't get why it happens

Comment: Can you post your view code please. I see the filter that eliminates the rows (67 -> 34 in "right" plan, 67 -> 19 in "wrong") but without code it's difficult to understand where it is.

Comment: SELECT TOP (SELECT dbo.f_6sigm_extra_tickets())
  row_number()
  OVER (
    ORDER BY id DESC ) AS rn,
  tu,
  id
FROM t2

Comment: No, that is not the view from your query. Your view has many conditions: [DM].[dbo].[OTRS_TICKET_ALL].[SERVICE_ID] as [ota].[SERVICE_ID]<>(25) AND ([DM].[dbo].[OTRS_TICKET_ALL].[QUEUE_ID] as [ota].[QUEUE_ID]=(20) OR [DM].[dbo].[OTRS_TICKET_ALL].[QUEUE_ID] as [ota].[QUEUE_ID]=(21)) AND ([DM].[dbo].[OTRS_TICKET_ALL].[TICKET_STATE_ID] as [ota].[TICKET_STATE_ID]=(2) OR [DM].[dbo].[OTRS_TICKET_ALL].[TICKET_STATE_ID] as [ota].[TICKET_STATE_ID]=(20))

Comment: WITH additional_tickets AS ( SELECT TOP (SELECT dbo.f_6sigm_extra_tickets()) row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ota.ID DESC ) AS rn, cast(ota.fact_tu_complete / 540 + 1 AS INT) AS tu, ota.id FROM OTRS_TICKET_ALL ota
 WHERE ota.queue_id IN (20, 21) AND ota.service_id != 25 AND ota.TICKET_STATE_ID IN (2, 20)) SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ota.ID DESC ) AS rn, cast(ota.fact_tu_complete / 540 + 1 AS INT) AS tu, ota.id FROM otrs_ticket_all ota
WHERE ota.queue_id IN (20, 21)
 AND ota.service_id != 25
 AND ota.TICKET_STATE_ID NOT IN (2, 20)
UNION ALL
SELECT
 rn, tu, id FROM additional_tickets

Comment: Function f_6sigm_extra_tickets selects data from table 'otrs_ticket_all', which is updated once a day, and should always produce the same result. Also filters in this function never change. Thank you so much for trying to help.

Comment: Yes you are right, it produces 67 rows in both cases. But that 67 rows ARE DIFFERENT in two cases. And when you filter them further the result set is different

Comment: I'll try now to demonstrate it to you

Comment: I got what you mean. When I select all fields, result set is sorted by ID. When I select only TU, data is not sorted by ID and therefore it has different values. Issue solved by adding another order (ORDER BY ota.ID DESC) after where clause to view additional_tickets. Thank you.